# Hibernate SQL Query result Mapping/Convert TO Object/Class/Bean

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

1 2: select (table.*)/(all column) is OK

```
String sql = "select t_student.* from t_student";
//String sql = "select t_student.id,t_student.name,... from t_student"; //select all column
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Student.class);//or query.addEntity("alias", Student.class);
//query.list();[Student@..., Student@..., Student@...]
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP); //or other transformer
query.list(); //[{Student(or alias)=Student@...},{Student=Student@...}]
```

3: select some column(not all of), is Error

```
String sql = "select t_student.id,t_student.name.t_student.sex from t_student";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Student.class);
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
query.list(); //Exception:invalid column/no column
```

I want "3" to work ok, and let the result can be mapped to Student.class.
Like: Student[id=?, name=?, sex=?, (other field are null/default)]
I've no idea for this error, help me please!

Comment: why using sql query? when you can use hql or criteria? you put `hql` instead of `sql` in 3 a mistake :P

Comment: haha!I just show a sample.In fact, Some bussiness must be implemented by sql.

Answer (score 25):

You can go further and add
`.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YOUR_DTO.class));`
and automatically map it to your custom dto object, see also [Returning non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e17636).

For example:

```
public List<MessageExtDto> getMessagesForProfile2(Long userProfileId) {
    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("  "
            + " select a.*, b.* "
            + " from messageVO AS a "
            + " INNER JOIN ( SELECT max(id) AS id, count(*) AS count FROM messageVO GROUP BY messageConversation_id) as b ON a.id = b.id "
            + " where a.id > 0 "
            + " ")
            .addScalar("id", new LongType())
            .addScalar("message", new StringType())
            ......... your mappings
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MessageExtDto.class));

    List<MessageExtDto> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: It should be usefull, but i'm so lazy, i was thought it can be transformed automatically.

Answer (score 4):

> I want "3" to work ok, and let the result can be mapped to Student.class

That's possible using
[`Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, String resultSetMapping`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

In the second argument you could tell the name of the result mapping. For example:

1) Let's consider a **Student** entity, the magic is going to be in the SqlResultSetMapping annotation:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "STUDENT_MAPPING", classes = {@ConstructorResult(
    targetClass = Student.class, columns = {
      @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
      @ColumnResult(name = "address")
})})
public class Student implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private String address;

   /* Constructor for the result mapping; the key is the order of the args*/ 
   public Student(String aName, String anAddress) {
       this.name = aName;
       this.address = anAddress;
   }

   // the rest of the entity
}
```

2) Now you can execute a query which results will be mapped by `STUDENT_MAPPING` logic:

```
String query = "SELECT s FROM student s";
String mapping = "STUDENT_MAPPING";
Query query = myEntityManager.createNativeQuery(query, mapping);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Student> students = query.getResultList();
for (Student s : students) {
   s.getName(); // ...
}
```

*Note*: I think it's not possible to avoid the unchecked warning.

Answer (score 3):

There is only two ways.

You can use 1st or 2nd snippet. According to Hibernate documentation you must prefer 2nd.

You can get just a list of object arrays, like this:

```
String sql = "select name, sex from t_student";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addScalar("name", StringType.INSTANCE); 
query.addScalar("sex", StringType.INSTANCE); 
query.list();
```

Comment: Thank you.  Use query.setResultTransformer({custom transformer}) after addScalar, can convert to Student.class,but I don't want it this way.

Comment: I want it be a Object instance of Student, is there anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on HQL Query. I solved the problem by changing the transformer.

The problem caused the code written to transform as Map. But it is not suitable for Alias Bean. You can see the error code at below. The code written to cast result as map and put new field to the map.

Class : org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessMapImpl.SetterImpl
m
Method: set

```
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void set(Object target, Object value, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
        ( (Map) target ).put( propertyName, value );
    }
```

I solved the problem to duplicate the transformer and change the code.

You can see the code in the project.

Link : https://github.com/robeio/robe/blob/DW1.0-migration/robe-hibernate/src/main/java/io/robe/hibernate/criteria/impl/hql/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java

Class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;

import io.robe.hibernate.criteria.api.query.SearchQuery;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class AliasToBeanResultTransformer extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.class);

    private final Class resultClass;

    // Holds fields of Transform Class as Map. Key is name of field. 
    private Map<String, Field> fieldMap;

    public AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Class resultClass) {
        if ( resultClass == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "resultClass cannot be null" );
        }
        fieldMap = SearchQuery.CacheFields.getCachedFields(resultClass);
        this.resultClass = resultClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases, int tupleLength) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Object result;
        try {
            result = resultClass.newInstance();
            for ( int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++ ) {
                String name = aliases[i];
                Field field = fieldMap.get(name);

                if(field == null) {
                    LOGGER.error(name + " field not found in " + resultClass.getName() + " class ! ");
                    continue;
                }
                field.set(result,  tuple[i]);
            }
        }
        catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate resultclass: " + resultClass.getName() );
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate resultclass: " + resultClass.getName() );
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

After created new Transformer You can use like below.

```
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(YOUR_DTO.class));
```

Comment: Can't find the io.robe.hibernate.criteria.api.query.SearchQuery Can you help in this regard? I used this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.robe/robe-hibernate/0.5.0.0-1039

Answer (score 0):

You can mapped it automatically:

1. Your Model Student.java

   public class Student {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   }
2. Repository

   String sql = "Select * from student";
   Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Student.class);
   List ls = query.getResultList();

- so it will automatically mapped the result with the Student class