# query with filed in where clause of HQL Query but dont want to select that filed

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table("abc")
public class Portfolio {

    @Id
    @Column(name="account_number")
    @JsonProperty("account_number")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name="query_email")
    private String query_email;
}
```

HQL Query :
**From Portfolio where query_email='abc@gamil.com'**

above query selecting ***query_email***, i don't need that.
i want to ignore the query_email on select.
if i use @Transient its not allowing me to query with  **query_email**

is there any other solution for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Use projections on constructor.

Query:

```
select new Portfolio(accountNumber) From Portfolio where query_email='abc@gamil.com'
```

You need add the contrucor with the same types that the query.

```
@Entity
@Table("abc")
public class Portfolio {

    @Id
    @Column(name="account_number")
    @JsonProperty("account_number")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name="query_email")
    private String query_email;

    public Portfolio(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public Portfolio() {
    }
}
```

---

Or then use **query.setResultTransformer(Portfolio.class)**:

[Hibernate SQL Query result Mapping/Convert TO Object/Class/Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355980/hibernate-sql-query-result-mapping-convert-to-object-class-bean)

Comment: thanks for quick replay but, i have to distinctly select around 50 other fields  from that table. can i select distinct row using projections on constructor?

Comment: Then you can use @Formula("SOME QUERY HERE") on query_email field, with any query that returns empty value. But it is a big and ugly work around....

Comment: Yes, you can select distinct row using **distinct** keyword.