# Transformers.aliasToBean() argument type mismatch

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

i have hibernate criteria with specific projection list:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("contract.autoId"), "contractId")
            .add(Projections.property("customer.firstName"), "firstName")
            .add(Projections.property("contract.startDate"), "startDate")
            .add(Projections.property("contract.endDate"), "endDate"));
```

I want to map the response of this criteria to the following DTO object:

```
public class Contract {
    private int contractId;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

The types of response for this criteria:
[image]
So, first object has **Long** type, but in DTO *contractId* has **int** type.I don't have permission to change this dto object.
So, when i added **ResultTransformer** to my criteria:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Contract.class));
```

I got following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Is it possible to say to **Transformers.aliasToBean** to convert automatically value from Long type to int?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355980/hibernate-sql-query-result-mapping-convert-to-object-class-bean

Comment: which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: @Leviand, i'm using 4.2.6

Comment: You can provide your custom Transformer

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your type by using the `addScalar` method, which will take care of transforming your result to expected type.
But afaik, it can only be done with `Native Query`. So you have first to convert your projection to a query, then add the scalar:

```
yourSession
    .createSQLQuery("select autoId, firstName, startDate, endDate from ...")
    .addScalar("contractId") //or you can specify the type with .addScalar("contractId", Hibernate.TheTypeYouWant)
```

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html

Comment: ok, it's a solution. But i'm not a big fan of writing native sql queries. And i think it's better to create custom ResultTransformer and make proper type casting by hands. I just thought, that maybe there is some way to do it automatically.

Comment: me neither, but if is a "one shot" query you can achieve you result faster then creating a custom ResultTransformer , but I agree with you! One of the many possible solutions ;)  . Glad it helped