# in java, i get ClassCastExceptin at the time of get the List<MailData> because of Returning non-managed entities

Tags: hibernate

when i iterate by using the foreach loop, i get ClassCast Exception. i dont know why ?

```
public List<MailData> getAllMailData() {
 String strqry="select c.created_time as created_time, c.hangup_time as hangup_time, c.direction as direction ,
     c.sip_endpoint_disposition as sip_endpoint_disposition, v.cid_number as cid_number, v.in_folder as in_folder, 
     v.message_len as message_len,v.read_flags as read_flags, v.username as username from onyxcxm_db.cdr c  
     inner join onyxcxm_db.mail_msgs v on c.orig_id=v.uuid";    

 List<MailData> listMailData = (List<MailData>)getSession().createNativeQuery(strqry).list();

   for(MailData md:listMailData){
    System.out.println(md.getcreated_time);  //line 44
       }
        getSession().flush();
    return listvoiceMailData;   
}
```

and Error like,

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/hello] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot
>   be cast to com.my.models.MailData] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.my.models.MailData    at
>   com.neron.daoImpl.MailDataDaoImpl.getAllMailData(MailDataDaoImpl.java:44)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Can any one solve it ? Thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate SQL Query result Mapping/Convert TO Object/Class/Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355980/hibernate-sql-query-result-mapping-convert-to-object-class-bean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use addScalar you can do this:

```
List<MailData> listMailData = getSession().createSQLQuery(strqry)
.addEntity(MailData.class)
.list();
```

Comment: Wow thanks, addEntity() is also a good solution. and new addScallar() is depricated in Hibernate 5 and `.list()` is also depricated you can update it as  `.getResultList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get the Solution using Query:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(strqry)  
             .addScalar("created_time", new StringType())      
             .addScalar("hangup_time", new StringType())  
             .addScalar("direction", new StringType())      
             .addScalar("sip_endpoint_disposition", new StringType())  
             .addScalar("cid_number", new StringType())      
             .addScalar("in_folder", new StringType())  
             .addScalar("read_flags", new StringType())      
             .addScalar("username", new StringType())  
             .addScalar("username", new StringType())  
             .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MailData.class));

     List<MailData> listMailData = query.getResultList();
```